# Searching for partial string in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react and have inherited an application that i need to understand while having to make some modifications.
The issue here is that, when a person search for "Micro" only a list of Micro is returned, when the expectation is that Microsoft and any other company that includes the term Micro will be returned, how do i accomplish this?

here's my code for searchResult component

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {PaginationControl} from "./PaginationControl";
import {SearchTable} from "./SearchTable";
import {Row, Col} from "reactstrap";
import './Search.css';

export class SearchResults extends Component {
    static defaultProps = {
        pageSize: 20
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            search: '',
            sort: null,
            filters: {},
            results: {
                items: [],
                page: 0,
                total: 0,
            },
            collection: 'software'
        };
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if ((prevProps.search !== this.props.search) ||
            (prevProps.collection !== this.props.collection) ||
            (prevProps.filters !== this.props.filters)) {
            this.search(0);
        }
    }

    async search(page) {
        let search = this.props.search;
        let collection = this.props.collection;
        if (search === null) {
            this.setState({
                results: {
                    items: [],
                    page: 0,
                    total: 0,
                },
                search: search,
            })
        } else {
            const request = {
                "search": search,
                "page" : page,
                "pageSize" : this.props.pageSize,
                "filter": this.props.filters,
                "sort": this.props.sort
            }
            let myCallback = this.setState.bind(this);
            fetch('search/product/' + collection,
                {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Accept': 'application/json',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify(request)
                }).then(function(response) {
                return response.json();
            }).then(function(data) {
                myCallback({results: data, search: search, collection: collection, loading: false});
            });
        }
    }

    selectPage(newPage) {
        this.search(newPage).then();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Row style={{ padding: 10}}>
                    <Col>
                        <b>Search:</b> "<i>{this.state.search}</i>"
                        (TotalHits: {this.state.results.total})
                    </Col>
                    <Col md="auto">
                        <PaginationControl className="my-pagination" page={this.state.results.page}
                                           pageSize={this.props.pageSize} total={this.state.results.total}
                                           pageHandler={p => this.selectPage(p)}/>
                    </Col>
                </Row>

                <SearchTable data={this.state.results.items}
                             cart={this.props.cart}
                             cartHandler={this.props.cartHandler}
                             actions={['add', 'copy']}/>
                             
            </div>
        );
    }

}
```

This is the SearchTable component

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {SearchRow} from './SearchRow';
import {ProductDetails} from './ProductDetails'

// Implementation of the Search Table
// To use <SearchTable data={results}></SearchTable>

export class SearchTable extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            modal: false,
            inspectRow: null
        };
    }

    
    render() {
        let results = this.props.data;
        return (
            <div>  
            <table className='table table-striped' aria-labelledby="tableLabel">
                    <tbody>
                    {results?.map(row => <SearchRow key={row.bdnaId}
                                                    data={row}
                                                    onInspect={(r) => this.setState({modal: true, inspectRow: r})}
                                                    actions={this.props.actions}
                                                    cartHandler={this.props.cartHandler}/>)}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <ProductDetails modal={this.state.modal} toggleModal={() => this.setState({modal: !this.state.modal})} row={this.state.inspectRow}/>
            </div>
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: It seems to me that your APi is not returning Microsoft when you search for Micro. I did not see an actual filter that could cause that behavior. Am I missing something?

Comment: @William that is exactly my question, this app is react + .net core + sql server. what modification I need to make to get Microsoft, MicroStrategy...back

Comment: It's not on the react application. Your query/stored procedure is probably using '=' to retrieve when it should be using a LIKE syntax.

Comment: Thanks will look into it and report

Answer (score 0):

Just adding the answer of what was discussed on the comment section. It appears that your `search` method binds whatever was returned from `search/product` back to the components state:

```
then(function(data) {
    myCallback({results: data, search: search, collection: collection, loading: false})
}
```

So it would appear that your filter is just fine on react. My guess is that the reason you are not getting "Microsoft" back when you filter by "Micro" is that your SQL query or Stored Procedure is using equals '=' instead of a `LIKE` syntax.

Comment: Thanks a lot @William I tried to dig deeper, and it appears that this is handled by ElasticSearch, I am researching on how to modify the code to get this back.